# Disabling su - <user1> alone

Tags: password, su

In my Team , we have a server which few people know the root password
I can see they log into root and then use

```
su - user1
```

to use from user1 login., I cannot change root password for some reasons , all i want to do is disabling then to do su - user1

at the same time , all other users does not need to follow this., they can be logged from root from su -

Answer (score 1):

**Not possible**. If you have root access with some way to prevent su for user X, then you also have the reverse way to allow su for user X. So, as long as your team has sudo access to root, there is no 100% solution, because the locked user X has to simply sudo, su to you & revert his locked state.

If you can not change the root password (or revoke sudo access), you can only make the rules and tell your team that any violations will be taken seriously.